# Difference between bootstrap.css and web.css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I was following this tutorial on Microsoft's developer network concerning using asp.net and mvc model with sql database.  Here is the link to the tutorial that I was following
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started.

So basically, I wanted to play around with the design of the file which is defined in these three files bootstrap.css, bootstrap.min.css, and web.css.

As to my understanding , bootstrap is an html, css, and javascript framework which has the design for the elements already defined. In Visual Studio, I began to edit the bootstrap.css file by changing background-color of the jumbotron element. However, when I saved the file and ran my web application , I noticed that the color remained the same and did not change. But, when I defined the design for the .jumbotron element in the web.css file, the element's background color changed accordingly to red.

Essentially, what I want to know is if bootstrap.css is restricted for editing within the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is Bootstrap

I think you're trying to refer to the Twitter Bootstrap that is used all around the Internet. It contains most of the Styling techniques for the Elements, such as buttons, inputs etc.

When you edit a website's Stylesheet, (Bootstrap.css is a Style sheet and its name doesn't make it write/edit protected file) you get the style that you've applied to it.

http://getbootstrap.com/

#### Web.css

This file might be the default Style sheet that was created by the Developers at Microsoft while creating the Template for the Website that you're using.

Secondly, when you edit and create this file, it is also a Style Sheet which means it would apply the style to your website and all the web pages who are refering to it.

You're right. It has all the pre-defined methods and contains all of the contents and styles required to make a web page **responsive**. For more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

What might have caused this problem would be **cache**. When you first loaded the web page, it would have captured the New Style sheet from the file System and would have applied the styles. But second time it would have loaded the File from the Cache.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)

This way, the browser would load the last successive layout of the Web Page. Without loading a new StyleSheet from the File System.

I really think, you need to reload the page using CTRL + F5 button. This would be helpfull in this manner! Because Bootstrap.css is editable and you can edit it. It doesn't prevent editing, only caching would be the problem here.